# CSS control on table row height

Tags: web-part, css

I have a problem with the height of `th` rows in a `table`.
The table is created by a webpart (a view of a wiki pages library).
I found the row height depending on the following class(es):

`.ms-listviewtable` (also `.ms-itmhover` and `.ms-itmhoverEnabled`)

Using Chrome dev tools I can change successfully the table rows height changing the `.ms-listviewtable` `.ms-itmhover` height (until rows shrink eachother), but if I set the same value in the script of my page, it does not work at all.

[image: what happens in chrome dev...]

[image: here the page edited]
Does anybody have some idea about what to do? I already checked all possible classes, but the row height seems to be frozen.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the class to manipulate. It is the `.ms-rtestate-read`. So if I just give `.ms-rtestate-read:line-height:70%` I get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ms-listviewtable .ms-itmhover` is more specific than just `.ms-itmhover` or `.ms-listviewtable` using in your second picture.

So the browser uses the`.ms-listviewtable .ms-itmhover` style.

Comment: But the ".ms-listviewtable .ms-itmhover" is not a style, it is just a serie os classes.... however I cannot use such a definition in a script, but just a class at once.
By the way in the page code I found something strange:
'<tr class=" ms-itmHoverEnabled ms-itmhover" ...'
with an empty space before the class name. Can it cause the problem? I have already used this kinf od script to shrink the tables, but here it diesn't work

Comment: I don't think that space can cause any problem. Why can't you use multiple class in your script?

Comment: I can use them, but comma separated. Anyway also giving to the script ".ms-listviewtable, .ms-itmhover, .ms-itmhoverEnabled {height:15px; background-color:yellow;}" I have no result... apart the yellow background I put just to check. So it seems that all controls work, but the height or line-height controls...
"

Comment: "Comma separated" means that you apply the style to each single class. But the combination of class just more [specifics](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) then each single class definition. If you are using jQuery then you can use ".ms-listviewtable.ms-itmhover" for multiclass selection.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use CSS scripts :(

Comment: Still does not work :( I tried with --- <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("div.ms-listviewtable.ms-itmhover:contains('Description')").css("height", "20px");});</script> ---- have no result.